# mail: command not found where running in Git bash

Tags: git, shell

When executed below script in GIT BASH, it shows the following message:

> mail: command not found" echo "**HTML Message goes here**" | mail
>   -s "$(echo -e "This is the subject\nContent-Type: text/html")" dineshl@gmail.com

How can I send HTML files by email? Could you please help us to resolve this?

Comment: This isn't a `bash` question, it's a system configuration question. You haven't mentioned what operating system you're using, so it's hard to give you a specific recommendation. It sounds like your system doesn't have any (or at least the most common) mail tools installed on it. A variety of them exists, and your sysadmin will have a preferred or recommended toolset and configuration for you.

Comment: Installing `mail` is superficially a simple task of `apt-get install (missing thing)` but setting up *working* outbound email delivery requires local configuration details which may be more or less trivial but impossible for us to tell you. This is not a programming question, anyway; voting to close as off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have used windows 10,Could you please provide toolset for configuration.

Comment: If you ask on the right forum, they can tell you what you need to ask your local network administrator. But you should probably just ask them directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is regarding HTML mails, but the issue the error message is hinting at is that the `mail` executable is missing. Please contact the system administrator and ask for a working mail setup. Maybe you can use `sendmail` instead of `mail`.

Comment: Maybe you can use sendmail instead of mail.
Here the result:
$ echo "hello world" | sendmail -s "a subject" dineshl@gmail.com
bash: sendmail: command not found
My question was email commands not working so how to fix it??

Comment: "contact the system administrator and ask for a working mail setup"

Answer (score 1):

[Git for Windows](http://gitforwindows.org/)'s Git Bash simply does not ship with `mail`, and there's no easy way to install it, either.